# Text Highlighting in Android Honeycomb 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am working on an application for Android Honeycomb 3.0 i.e. for the tablets.
My application is basically a book where each chapter comes in the form of Webview.
Now when we long press any word the action bar changes automatically with several options like - Select All, copy, share ,find etc.

I want to know that is there any way that we can customize this new action bar ? I mean can we add some of our own items in this action bar which automatically appears on long press?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know that is there any way that we can customize this new action bar ? I mean can we add some of our own items in this action bar which automatically appears on long press?

Yes and no.

What you are seeing is called an action mode, and you can call [`startActionMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActionMode%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) to create one. However, I cannot think of any way that you can get involved in `WebView`'s own action mode.

Comment: FYI, [there is currently an ongoing initiative against using URL shorteners in posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136/152101) As a >100K rep user who appears not to know that, I figured I should let you know.  :)

Comment: @John: The only places I use URL shorteners is when the URL is not considered valid by SO, such as links to methods in JavaDocs (parentheses give SO problems).

Comment: I realized that was most likely why when I went to remove the shortener, but I figured better you were told twice than not at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare When we long press content on web view (Android 3.0), we get this option called copy which copies the highlighted text to the clipboard. I want to know how can we do this ourselves i.e. by not using the copy button. How do we copy/get the highlighted text from webview

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare is correct that you cannot currently get involved in WebView's ActionMode.Callback, which is the class that implements the Contextual Action Bar during WebView's text selection mode.

I filed a feature request for this so hopefully this will be improved in the future:
Issue 24841: WebView should allow applications to supply a custom Contextual Action Bar
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24841

Note that you cannot get the selection from the WebView either.  It is a linked feature request from the one above.  Basically, the getSelection() method needs to become public.